# PYTHON ISSUE BEGGINGER CODE - TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Tags: python, exception

I'm learning how to create lists and add two lists together - here's what I tried

```py
my_list = ('one' , 'two' , 'three')
another_list =('four' , 'five')
new_list = (my_list + another_list)
print(new_list)
```

however, when running it, I get an Exception

```py
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Comment: I don't get any errors when running that. As a sidenote, `list`s use square-brackets `[]`, and are mutable. `tuple`s use parentheses `()` and are immutable.

Comment: I see what I've done! I forgot the # out some of the previous stuff I was doing.

Comment: thank you for your help ! I typed out what I meant to put from the ide into this comment box, and it worked on its own.

Answer (score 2):

For lists, you need to use square brackets - `[]` instead of parantheses - `()`. Try-

```
my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
another_list = ['four', 'five']
new_list = my_list + another_list

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I appreciate it